# Access 2013: Pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, ms-access-2013, tableau-api

I have a strange access database table that I need to pivot before using with Tableau. I'm using Access 2013. Data is totally fake but the structure is right.

There are 200 files, with about 1500 runs each. I have 50 years of metrics. I have about 10 metrics per file/run.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DataTable                                              |
+-------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| FileIDRunID |    Metric    | 1999 | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
+-------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| 00000100001 | Breakfast    | 45   | 47   | 48   | 49   |
| 00000100001 | Lunch        | 27   | 37   | 50   | 99   |
| 00000100002 | Breakfast    | 45   | 47   | 48   | 49   |
| 00000100002 | Lunch        | 27   | 37   | 50   | 99   |
| 00000200001 | Breakfast    | 45   | 47   | 48   | 49   |
| 00000200001 | Lunch        | 27   | 37   | 50   | 99   |
| 00000200002 | Breakfast    | 45   | 47   | 48   | 49   |
| 00000200002 | Lunch        | 27   | 37   | 50   | 99   |
+-------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
```

I would like to pivot and have the metrics as columns and the years as individual rows.

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| DataTableView                                  |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| FileIDRunID |    Year      | Breakfast | Lunch |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| 00000100001 | 1999         | 45        | 47    |
| 00000100001 | 2000         | 27        | 37    | 
| 00000100002 | 1999         | 45        | 47    | 
| 00000100002 | 2000         | 27        | 37    |
| 00000200001 | 1999         | 45        | 47    | 
| 00000200001 | 2000         | 27        | 37    | 
| 00000200002 | 1999         | 45        | 47    | 
| 00000200002 | 2000         | 27        | 37    | 
+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

I managed to pivot one year.

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(DataTable.[1999])
SELECT FileIDRunID, '1999' as Year
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY FileIDRunID
PIVOT DataTable.Metric
```

I think the next step is to UNION ALL with each year manually. When I try that with the next year though I get an error.

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(DataTable.[1999])
SELECT FileIDRunID, '1999' as Year
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY FileIDRunID
PIVOT DataTable.Metric
UNION ALL
TRANSFORM FIRST(DataTable.[2000])
SELECT FileIDRunID, '2000' as Year
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY FileIDRunID
PIVOT DataTable.Metric
```

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DataTable.Metric
    UNION ALL
    TRANSFORM FIRST(DataTable.[2000])
    SELECT FileID, RunID, '2000' as Year
    FROM DataTable
    GROUP BY FileIDRunID
    PIVOT DataTable.Metric'

I'm hoping someone here has a better idea :).

Comment: Woops. I don't :) Fixed

Comment: Data in the second set of columns isn't exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRANSFORM` can [only occur at the start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of an SQL statement.

First unpivot all the years and only then pivot the metric. Now, as MS Access apparently
has its limits when it comes to complex queries (many unions), it is best to pass via 
an intermediate table:

```
SELECT  FileIDRunID, Metric, Year, Value
FROM    (
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 1999 As Year, [1999] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2000 As Year, [2000] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2001 As Year, [2001] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2002 As Year, [2002] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
        )
INTO myTempTable;
```

I have `union`-ed 4 years, but you should check how far you can go before MS Access refuses the statement for being too complex. 
Then, add some more years, with the same number of `union`s:

```
INSERT INTO myTempTable (FileIDRunID, Metric, Year, Value)
SELECT  FileIDRunID, Metric, Year, Value
FROM    (
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2003 As Year, [2003] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2004 As Year, [2004] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2005 As Year, [2005] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      FileIDRunID, Metric, 2006 As Year, [2006] As Value
            FROM        DataTable
        );
```

etc... to finally do this:

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(Value)
SELECT   FileIDRunID,
         Year
FROM     myTempTable
GROUP BY FileIDRunID,
         Year
PIVOT    Metric
```

And then drop the temporary table and compress the database to get the original size back. If possible, redesign the database to use the completely unpivoted structure as in the temporary table.

Comment: Looking at yours, I think that I'm doing the same thing in my posted answer. Though, when I try to do the pivot, Access tells me the query is too complex. Any sense of whether this query will give the same result?

Comment: Just tried this, Access says it is too complex. I wonder if it can be done with less years in individual queries then unioned together.

Comment: Got it to run with 10 years of data.

Comment: What happens if you first create a view of the long subquery and then reference that in the TRANSFORM statement? OK, I see now you proposed that in your answer... hmmm.

Comment: This may be the kind of problem that just requires that the original table be reformatted... too much data to pivot.

Comment: Pivot isn't really the issue.  Access won't let you `UNION` 50 data sources. "Too complex."

Comment: mmmm going into a temp table will greatly increase the size of the access database though right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it will add the size of the original table to it in addition. But I see no other way now.

Comment: @HansUp, with which SQL would you do that load?

Answer (score 0):

Think I may have found 'an' answer. Still hoping for something more elegant.

First, convert individual columns to a single column into a new view called "DataTableFormatted"

```
SELECT FileIDRunID, Metric, '1999' as Year
FROM DataTable
UNION ALL
SELECT FileIDRunID, Metric, '2000' as Year
FROM DataTable
```

Then, perform the transform on that table.

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(DataValue)
SELECT FileIDRunID, Year
FROM DataTableFormatted
GROUP BY FileIDRunID, Year
PIVOT DataTableFormatted.Metric
```